# Error sendin email with Javamail: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 550 5.1.0 *@* sender rejected

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email programmatically to a set of recipients via Javamail. I setup a MimeMessagePreparator and I pass it to a JavaMailSenderImpl, but when sending the email I get the following:

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages:
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.1.0
>   <**mycomputer!!**> sender rejected

So, the sender looks like my computer.

This is my code:

```
public class EmailNotifier {

    private JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;
    @Value("${application.mail.sender.address}")
    private String senderEmail;
    @Value("${application.mail.subject}")
    private String emailSubject;
    @Value("${application.mail.sender.address}")
    private String senderAddress;
    @Value("${application.mail.sender.password}")
    private String senderPassword;
    @Value("${application.mail.server.outgoing.port}")
    private int outgoingPort;
    @Value("${application.mail.server.outgoing}")
    private String outgoingServer;
    @Value("${application.mail.content}")
    private String contentTemplate;
    private static String BODY_CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    private static String PDF_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/pdf";

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setPassword(senderPassword);
        mailSender.setUsername(senderAddress);
        mailSender.setPort(outgoingPort);
        mailSender.setHost(outgoingServer);
    }

    public void sendEmail(InputStream pdfInputStream, String aRecipient) throws MessagingException {

        final String commaSeparatedRecipientsEmail = getRecipients();

        String content = contentTemplate;
        MimeMessagePreparator msgPreparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {

            public void prepare(MimeMessage msg) throws Exception {
                msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, emailsAgenzia);
                msg.setSubject(emailSubject.replace(emailSubject);
                MimeBodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                bodyPart.setContent(content, BODY_CONTENT_TYPE);

                MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                ByteArrayDataSource pdf = new ByteArrayDataSource(pdfInputStream, PDF_CONTENT_TYPE);

                attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(pdf));
                String fileName = getFilename();
                attachmentPart.setFileName(fileName);

                Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
                multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
                msg.setContent(multipart);
            }
        };

        this.mailSender.send(msgPreparator);
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The problem may be that you are attempting to submit email directly from your desktop PC without going through a recognized mailhost.  Most _receiving_ SMTP servers use DNS blacklists that specifically exclude dynamic IP addresses, and if you are sending mail directly from a system whose external IP is dynamic, you will be rejected by most SMTP servers.  What is the value of `application.mail.server.outgoing`?  How do you authenticate to the outgoing server?

Comment: I am testing from my PC, but my outgoing server refers to a domain I registered. I am authenticating with username and password via SMTP.

Comment: You need to examine the logs on the server to see where the mail is being rejected.  Without that it's going to be impossible to troubleshoot.  Do you administer the SMTP server, or is that handled by your ISP?

Comment: Thanks, but it is administered by a service provider and it will take long to get a reply. If possible, I'd prefer to make some attempt to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually had to abandon JavaMailSenderImpl and use lower level API (Javamail basic classes rather than Spring classes).

Answer (score 0):

It's a DNS problem. You have to insert your sender address in the DNS system.

https://digitaltoolfactory.net/blog/2010/03/how-to-fix-the-550-5-1-0-address-rejected-email-problem/

Or maybe a mailaddress is not valid.

Comment: Thanks, I request to double check the MX record.

Comment: This may not be the problem.  See my comment on the question.

Comment: Oh ok, when I had the prob this solution fixed it. But I think the link with all comments provides a good information package how to deal with this error and possible causes.

Comment: Unfortunately, the domain is correctly configured. I tried with a different outgoing server, but the email does not get sent.